# Vortoj pri uzo de e-cigaredo

Tags: word-formation

Mi ne scias ĉu ekzistas vortoj en Esperanto por la uzado de elektronikaj cigaredoj. Pri tio mi nenion trovis. Aliaj lingvoj evitas vortojn kiel fumi, fumado, ktp. rilate al e-cigaredo. Ekz. en la angla oni trovas "(to) vape, vaping, vaporizer, vaper". En la hispana "vapear, vapeo, vaporizador, vapeador". En Esperanto mi uzas "vapei, vapeado, vapeilo/vaporilo, vapeanto". Mi ne multe scias pri vortfarado, sed al mi ŝajnas logike uzi la radikon *vape*- prefere al *vapor*- aŭ eĉ *vap*-, same kiel oni faras en aliaj lingvoj. Ĉu mia rezonado taŭgas?

Answer (score 5):

Mi ĝis nun renkontis nur la vorton „vaporumi” kaj mi ne vidas kialon, por inventi novan radikon. Vi skribas „same kiel oni faras en aliaj lingvoj”. Nu, certe ne en ĉiuj. En mia denaska lingvo la verbo estas *dampen*, kiu estas preciza traduko de „vaporumi”.

Comment: "Vaporumi" laŭ PIV signifas "vaporkuiri", kaj "vaporumilo" laŭ ReVo estas speco de per-vapora kuirilo aŭ vaporkuirilo. Bedaŭrinde tiuj vortaroj diras nenion pri kiom multe ĉi vortoj enradikiĝis lingvouze. Ĉiuokaze, mi celas vorton pli specifan aŭ eĉ fakan kaj samtempe kiel eble plej internacie rekoneblan.

Comment: Esperantistoj kutime evitas ke vortoj havu plurajn signifojn, sed mi ne pensas ke tio gravas por um-vortoj. Ilia signifo ĉefe venas de kunteksto, kaj ne de vortaroj. -um- estas helpa ilo kiam oni volas komuniki ideon de ago, kiu rilatas al la radiko, kiam oni ne konas la verbon aŭ kiam ĝi ne ekzistas. Malpermesi tion igus -um- multe malpli utila.

Comment: Konsentite, "vaporumi" estas tute uzebla manke de io pli bona, malgraŭ ke ĝi estas malpreciza kaj kunteksto-dependa.
Mi sopiras la facilecon per kiu iuj lingvoj kapablas tutnature krei novajn vortojn. La angla kreis "vape" el "vapour/vaporize", la hispana "vapear" el "vaporear", la franca "vapoter" el "vapeur", la itala "svapare" el "vapore", la sveda kreis "vejpa" rekte el la angla. 

La angla "vape" estis nomumita vorto de la jaro 2014 fare de Oxford Dictionaries.

Comment: La sufikso -um estas bonega ilo por la okaza kreaĵo de neekzistanta vorto, sed ne por kreado de memstara plenrajta vorto jam uzata en aliaj lingvoj. Se la "e-vaporilo" jam ekzistus komence de la 19-a jarcento, ni jam havus apartan vorton por ĝi, plej verŝajne fare de Zamenhof mem, kies pasio por fumi mallongigis lian propran vivon.

Answer (score 3):

Mi trovis interesan vort-proponon de Robert Molimard, franca kuracisto, profesoro pri fiziologio kaj fakulo pri problemoj rilataj al tabakfumado. Li kunfondis la Societo pri Tabakologio, kiun li prezidis dum 18 jaroj. Li ankaŭ parolas Esperanton, kiun li eklernis jam 77-jaraĝa. Jen lia opinio (rektaj krampoj estas miaj):

*Kvankam* [por] *enigo de novaj radikoj necesas granda singardeco, tamen preskaŭ ĉie aperis neologismoj. Angloj elektis "to vape, vaping, a vaper". "Vapi" estus la plej simpla solvo. Sed la francoj almetis diminutivon, eble ĉar "un vapeur" elvokas egan vaporŝipon. Tamen "vapoti", estas tro ligita al la franca lingvo.* [...] *Ekzistas en mia latina vortaro "vapos" (vaporo) kaj "vappa", t.e vino, el kiu elvaporiĝis alkoholo kaj aromoj. Do "vap" estus la vera radiko.*

Kompreneble Molimard klare distingas ke *fumi* kaj *uzi e-vaporilon* estas malsamaj aferoj, ĉar e-cigaredo ne estas cigaredo:

*Certe “elektronika cigaredo” ne estas cigaredo, same kiel la fama pentraĵo de Magritte ne "estas" pipo. Ambaŭ nur figuras, sed ne "estas". Fakte, ĝi estas elektra inhalilo, pseŭdocigaredo, iafoje pseŭdo-pipo aŭ pseŭdo–nargileo, kiu ebl[ig]as elspiri vaporon. Simple, ili estas "elektronika-vapiloj".*

La pripensoj de Molimard estas konsiderindaj pro du kialoj. Unue, li kiel multjara spertulo pri tabako kaj fumĉesado konkludas, ke estas klara malsameco inter fumado kaj uzado de e-vaporiloj. Due, li kiel studanto dum ses jaroj de la latina lingvo hipotezas, ke la priparolata vorto uzata en diversaj lingvoj devenas el komuna radiko, nome la latina "vap-", kies signifo rilatas al "vaporo".

La rezonado de Molimard klarigus kial la plimulto de la *vapuloj* evitas la vorton "fumi" kaj emas uzi alian vorton pli proksiman al la senco de vaporo. Laŭ mi, la vorto "vapi" estas simpla, eleganta kaj taŭga propono. Ke ĝin proponis fakulo pri tabako kaj fumĉesado estas des pli bone.

Fonto: [Elektronika cigaredo, estas seriozaĵo?](http://www.tabac-humain.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Elektronika-cigaredo.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

"Fumi" - oni ne ŝanĝas la verbon kiam la teknologio ŝanĝiĝas (ekzemple: *tondi* herbojn; laŭbezona *pres*ado.)

"Mi fumas vaporcigaredojn."

Comment: Oni ne fumas e-vaporilon, ĉar nenia bruligo okazas en ĝi kaj nenia fumo eliras el ĝi. La ĉefa kialo uzi ĝin estas ĉesi fumi por pli bona sano.

Comment: Herbotondilo ne tondas.  Laŭbezona presado nenion premas.

Comment: Ne nur la teknologio estas malsimila, sed ankaŭ la ago kaj la intenco estas tute malsimilaj. Oni bezonas aldoni novan linio al PIV, ReVo, kaj al multaj vortaroj se oni uzas la vorton tiel. Aŭ oni diru "fumigas", ĉar oni igas la aparaton fumi. Ankaŭ, mi pensas ke uzantoj de tia elektronikaĵo ne ĝojos ne povi diri "mi ĉesis fumi". Laŭ mi, klare estas volo inter la uzantoj distingi fumadon de cigaredo kaj "fumado" de tio per nova verbo.

Comment: Se la "intenco" estas tute malsama, kial ambaŭ nomiĝas "cigaredo"? Mi ne streĉas la terminon per mia insisto ke tio kion oni faras al cigaredo (ĉu elektronika ĉu tradicia) estas "fumado."

Comment: Estas kvazaŭ oni demandus jene: se veneno kaj kontraŭ-veneno havas malsaman celon, kial ambaŭ nomiĝas "veneno"? Tamen, malpravas ke ambaŭ nomiĝas same. Okazas ke ambaŭ enhavas komunan vorton (cigaredo), sed unu el ili havas aldonan vorton antaŭ si (elektronika). La kombinado de ambaŭ vortoj donas novajn signifon kaj celon: elektronika cigaredo aŭ e-cigaredo. Jen kial gravas uzi en Esperanto alian pli klaran vorton por eviti konfuzon, ekz. vapei, vapeilo, vapeanto, vapeado, ktp., same kiel aliaj lingvoj jam faras per normala lingvo-evoluo.

Comment: @Vidamuzo - Do bone. Se vi volas, vi povas dir ke oni e-fumas e-cigaredojn. Vere, mi ne streĉas la signifon de "fumi". "Revolutionary e-cigarette starter kits for every type of **vapor smokers**." "President Obama Smokes Electronic Cigarettes". "Millennials seem to be choosing e-smoking over traditional tobacco"

Comment: Aliaj dirus "President Obama Vapes Electronic Cigarettes". Sed neniu dirus "President Obama Vapes Traditional Cigarettes", ĉar tio simple ne eblas, ĉar fakte "smoke" kaj "vape" estas tute malsamaj aferoj, ne gravas kiel similaj ambaŭ aspektas. Oni rajtas diri laŭvole. Neniu rajtas malpermesi "vape", kiu fakte estas la ĝusta nomo, tiel ĝusta ke ĝi jam eniris en la anglan vortaron.

Comment: Mi ankaŭ uzus la vorton "fumi", mi ja uzas tiun en mia denaska lingvo. Supozeble tiu estus ankaŭ la vidpunkto de Claude Piron kaj la skolo de "bona lingvo" (elvokado prefere ol difinado). Finfine ni jam uzas amason da vortoj kiel "voĉdoni" aŭ "terpomo" ktp., kiuj ankaŭ estus malĝustaj laŭ strikta difina senco.

Answer (score 2):

Kvankam la aktuala modo en la angla estas uzi la vorton "vape", tio estas nova. Antaŭ "vaping" estis moda okupo, Diri simple ke oni uzas aŭ fumas elektrikan cigaredon estis kutima. Tial krei novan vorton aŭ plivastigi la signifojn de um-vorton ne necesas. Kvankam nenio bruliĝas dum la fumado de e-cigaredo, ĝi estas logika, subtila, kaj facile komprenebla disvastigo de la signifo de fumado.

Lingvo ofte restas priskribante teĥnologion, eĉ kiam teĥnologio ŝanĝiĝas. La baza celo de cigaredo, elektrika cigaredo, cigaro, pipo, nargileo, ktp. estas enspiri ian substancon por medicinaj avantaĝoj aŭ por ebriiĝi, do la intenco ja samas aŭ almenaŭ similas. Oni povas pretendi ke ĉar fumi cigaredon kaj uzi elektrikan cigaredon havas grandajn materialajn diferencojn. sed tio ne signifas ke nova vorto necesas. La agoj tamen ankaŭ havas facile videblajn similojn.

Konsiderante lernantojn, la elekto evidentiĝas. Se oni serĉas la tradukojn de "vape" en aliajn lingvojn (ex. "vapoter" france, kaj "vapear" hispane") je Google Trends, oni vidos ke tiuj vortoj komencis uziĝi nur post "vape" populariĝis. Pro la rapide kreskanta nombro de anglaj lingvanoj kiuj lernas Esperanton (kiu mem ne estas malbona afero), ĉiuj ni klopodu konservi la neŭtralecon kaj tutmondecon de Esperanto. Kiam nova teĥnologio ekestas, aŭ kiam sociologiaj situacioj ŝanĝiĝas, ŝanĝi niajn vortojn aŭ krei novajn vortojn 
eble necesos, sed importi nuntempajn anglajn modojn por esprimi ion, kion ni jam havas vortojn por facile esprimi, simple ne necesas.

Comment: Vorton uzata laŭlonge de preskaŭ jardeko mi ne taksus kiel modon. La sola fakto ke pli ol 30 milionoj da homoj tutmonde jam uzas tiun novan vorton anstataŭ "fumi" tute malkonstruas vian argumenton. Nenio malpermesas al vi plu uzi "fumi", se vi tiel volas. Ankaŭ nenio malpermesas al homoj la uzadon de nova vorto, kiun ili konsideras necesa aŭ utila.

Comment: Ĉu la zamenhofa "cigaredo" estas necesa? Ĉu ne sufiĉus "paper-cigareto" aŭ eĉ "cigareto" anstataŭ krei novan vorton preskaŭ identa, por cilindreto fabrikita per siatempe nova teknologia modo? Ĉu Zamenhof ne pensis pri la balasto de la vortprovizo kiam li kreis amason da "nenecesaj" novaj vortoj? Ni ĉiuj uzas novvortojn la tutan tempon, skribante "aktuala" anstataŭ "nuntempa", "nargileo" anstataŭ "akvopipo". Pri tio Zamenhof skribis en sia Fundamento ke "riĉigadi la lingvon per novaj vortoj oni povas jam nun".

Comment: Ĉu aŭ ĉu ne zamenhofa vorto necesas estas tute malsama diskuto. Ĝi estas zamenhofa kaj tiel ekzistis dum almenaŭ centjaro kaj dum la plejparto de la historio de Esperanto. Kiel Tomaso Aleksander diras, Esperanto ne ekestis hieraŭ. La punkto estas ke ni ne bezonas novan radikon; fumi funkcias pli ol sufiĉe bone.

Comment: Aldone, "nargileo" estas tipo de akvopipo el la mezoriento, kaj "aktuala" estas zamenhofa, ne novavorto aŭ "neologismo", ĝi eĉ uziĝis kun nuntempa en lia traduko de Marta. Cetere, preskaŭ jardeko estas nur unu tridekono de la vivo de Esperanto. "Vaping" ne fariĝis populara vorto ĝis ĉirkaŭ 2013 aŭ 2014 kiu ne estas eĉ jardeko. La uzo de "vape" per mondanoj evidente estas signo de la povo de anglaj *modoj* je la reto, kiu ne estas iu, kiun Esperanto simple obeu, aparte se ni jam havas vortojn por facile esprimi tian agon. Esperantistoj ja kreas aŭ kunmetas novavortojn, sed ne sen grava bezono.

Comment: La angla "vape" estis elpensita de Rob Stepney en 1983, kiam li hipotezis en revua artikolo pri ia estonta e-vaporilo. Laŭ _Oxford Dictionaries_ la vorto publike ekpopulariĝis en 2009. Pasis jam 8 jaroj ĝis 2017, do preskaŭ jardeko. Ĝi jam estis populara antaŭ 2013 kaj en 2014 atingis pinton de populareco, eniris en la anglan vortaron kaj eĉ estis nomumita vorto de la jaro.

Comment: Laŭ vi "la punkto estas ke **ni** ne bezonas novan radikon" kaj "**fumi funkcias** pli ol sufiĉe bone". Kiu estas tiu "ni"? Por kiu "fumi" funkcias? Ĝi certe ne funkcias por ĉirkaŭ 30 milionoj da homoj, kiuj jam delonge uzas en siaj diversaj lingvoj novan vorton alian ol "fumi". Kial devas esti alie en la t.n. internacia lingvo? Ĉu pro kaprico? Ĉu pro ia fobio al novaj vortoj aŭ al la e-vaporilo mem aŭ al iu aparta lingvo? Mi simple ne povas konsenti pri tio.

Comment: Ĉiu esperanta vorto estis iam nova aŭ neologisma iasence, ĉu zamenhofa aŭ ne. Vortoj kiel _liva, frida, zorio, gejo aŭ mojosa_ ne ekzistis plejparte de la historio de Esperanto. Ĉu "zorio" kaj "gejo" estas ankaŭ importoj de japana respektive angla modoj? Laŭ mi tute ne sed iuj ankoraŭ pensas ke "ni ne bezonas la vorton _gejo_, ĉar _samseksemulo_ funkcias bone". Mi ankaŭ ne povas konsenti pri tio.

Comment: Mi konsentas ke por krei novan vorton necesas grava bezono, sed tio, kio gravas por iuj ne nepre gravas por aliaj. Verkistoj ofte kreas vortojn pro bezono de esprimriĉeco sed tio ne nepre signifas ke la ceteraj esperantistoj sentas bezonon de tiaj vortoj. Modo povas ankaŭ krei vortojn, kiuj ofte malaperas kune kun la fino de la modo. Ankaŭ tiuj vortoj rajtas efemere ekzisti.

Comment: Mia demando temas pri vortfarado de nova vorto, ne pri la rajto krei ĝin, kion jam klarigis Zamenhof antaŭ pli ol jarcento. Mi ne pretendas altrudi vorton al aliaj. Mi nur volas uzi specifan vorton en simila maniero kiel la e-vaporila komunumo faras en siaj lingvoj. "Fumi" estas evidente tute ne akceptebla. "Vaporumi" estas  malpreciza kaj tial uzebla sed ne uzinda. Ĉiu faru laŭ sia bontrovo. Persone mi sekvos la konsilojn de Zamenhof.

Comment: Mi ne disputos kun vi. Stack Exchange ne estas forumo. Vi demandis pri la vorto por esprimi la uzadon de **elektrika cigaredo**, kaj mi kaj Tomaso Alexander diris ke fumi jam ekzistas kaj funkcias. Meti komenton post komenton kaj diri tiel sensencaĵojn kiel "Ĉu "**zorio**" kaj "gejo" estas ankaŭ importoj de japana respektive angla modoj?" montras al mi ke vi jam decidis respondon demandinte.

Comment: Mi demandis ĉu mia vortfarado pri vorto **alia ol fumi** estas taŭga kaj mi donis ekzemplon: "vapei". Kaj jen preskaŭ ĉiu respondo insistis pri la uzado de "fumi". Diri ke "fumi funkcias pli ol sufiĉe bone" ne estas respondo al mia demando. Mi ne disputas, mi argumentas, espereble por plibonigi la respondojn.

Comment: Vi demandis se tio estus taŭga, kaj ni diris ne.

Comment: Necesas nur legi la respondojn por konstati ke neniu donis respondon pri la taŭgeco de mia vortfarado, sed pri siaj opinio kaj antaŭjuĝo eviti vortfaradon de nova vorto.